# writing data to xml SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, xml, swift3

How to write data to the xml file?

Maybe anyone know XMLWriter for swift 3 or etc?

I have a scoreboard in my game and I want to save int data to the xml file in my project, ow can I do this?

In Objective C version XMLWriter I catch error at conversation.

update 1:

```
class XML: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    let xmlParser: XMLParser
    var scores = [XMLData]()
    var topData: XMLData?
    var xmlText = ""

    init(withXML xml: NSData) {
        self.xmlParser = XMLParser(data: xml as Data)
    }

    func parse() -> [XMLData] {
        xmlParser.delegate = self
        xmlParser.parse()
        return scores
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        if elementName == "hightScore" {
            topData = XMLData()
        }
        if elementName == "topOne" {
            xmlText = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "topOne" {
            let text = xmlText.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
            if let topScore = Int(text) {
                topData?.topScore = topScore
            }
        }

        if elementName == "hightScore" {
            if let hightScore = topData {
                scores.append(hightScore)
            }
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        xmlText += string
    }
}

class XMLData: CustomStringConvertible {
    var topScore = 0

    var description: String {
        return "\(topScore)"
    }
}
```

and:

```
func readXML() {
        if let xmlUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Score", withExtension: "xml") {
            do {
                let xmlText = try String(contentsOf: xmlUrl)
                if let xmlData = xmlText.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    let parser = XML(withXML: xmlData as NSData)
                    for score in parser.parse() {
                        gameSetting.topScore = score.topScore
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A little code never killed nobody. Please, we ask you to show us your `function`s, `data model`s or whatever you have in mind so far. For help, check out [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: dirtydanee, i done

Comment: are you trying to read or write `XML` ?

Comment: i know how read xml, i do not know how write data to xml